# Deny Local Logon Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I'm trying to apply a New GPO that deny Local Logon in my client pc's but its not working even if i applied steps :
Computer Configuration > Policies > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Deny log on locally

[image]

Comment: have you used gpresult or rsop to verify that the policy is being applied to the computer after running `gpudate /force`?

Comment: yes i've already verified on the client computer that the policy is applied already !

Comment: What exactly isn't working? How is it not working? How are you logging on to these clients?

Comment: the local access to computer still working even if i apply this GPO! i can logon to the Desktop_LAB1 using a local accounts already created on it !! i don't know what's wrong with this GPO!!

Comment: Based on the screenshot, you haven't added any of those local accounts to the list, only a computer account (which can't be logged into anyway) and the `SPDI` domain account.  Only accounts that appear in the list will be prevented from logging in.  So at the moment `SPDI` is the only account that will be prevented from logging in.

Comment: okay thank you , so i should add local accounts of that clients ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, it seems that you added computers or computers group in this policy.

You must add users or groups containing users and not computers, because the purpose of this policy is to prevent users to log on.

Comment: yes but i'm wondering if i should apply it to Computer Configuration or USer Configuration ?

Comment: It's a Computer Configuration setting. You configure the computer to prevent specific users to log on.

Comment: Take a look at the 'explain' tab as to how this setting works. The idea is to apply this 'computer' policy to a computer with the accounts you want denied from logon listed here. So you can make a "Deny Joe" GPO with "CONTOSO\Joe" listed in this policy and link the "Deny Joe" GPO to the OU where the "Computer01" system is located. Then, "CONTOSO\Joe" won't be able to locally log on to any machine in that OU.